# PMD rules: How to properly solve this DD-anomaly issue

Tags: java, code-analysis, pmd, dataflow, static-code-analysis

I have the following Android code:

```
public final List<MyObj> getList()  {
    Cursor cursor = null;
    try {
        final String queryStr = GET_LIST_STATEMENT;
        cursor = db.rawQuery(queryStr, new String[] {});
        List<MyObj> list = null;
        //here I get the data from de cursor.
        return list ;
    } catch (SQLiteFullException ex) {
        //do something to treat the exception.
    } finally {
        if (cursor != null) {
            cursor.close();
        }
    }
}
```

When I run PMD analysis over this code, I get the following issue: `Found 'DD'-anomaly for variable 'cursor' (lines '182'-'185').`

- The line 182 is: `Cursor cursor = null;`.
- The line 185 is: `cursor = db.rawQuery(queryStr, new String[] {});`

So, I understand that the problem is that I'm doing a Premature Initialization in the line 182 (I never read the variable between the lines 182 and 185), but if I don't do that, I can't have the code closing the `cursor` in the finally block.

What to do in this case? Just ignore this PMD issue? Can I configure PMD to don't rise up this specific kind of DD-anomaly (not all DD-anomaly)? Should PMD be smart enough to doesn't rise up this issue?

Another example of DD-anomaly that I think is not a real problem:

```
    Date distributeDate;
    try {
        distributeDate = mDf.parse(someStringDate);
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        Log.e("Problem", "Problem parsing the date of the education. Apply default date.");
        distributeDate = Calendar.getInstance().getTime();
    }
```

In this case, the anomaly occurs with the `distributeDate` variable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [documentation](http://pmd.sourceforge.net/pmd-5.0.1/suppressing.html) is pretty easy to understand:

Either you use annotations to suppress warnings:

```
// This will suppress UnusedLocalVariable warnings in this class
@SuppressWarnings("PMD.UnusedLocalVariable")
public class Bar {
 void bar() {
  int foo;
 }
}
```

or you use a comment:

```
public class Bar {
 // 'bar' is accessed by a native method, so we want to suppress warnings for it
 private int bar; //NOPMD
}
```

When it comes to your specific code, I'd say that the easiest way to handle it is to not use a `finally` block even though this would look like the perfect place for it.